# Trying to use php include in an errordocument page but it doesn't work in different directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, include-path, errordocument

I think I found that when I have an errordocument custom error page, include does not always work because the include requires a directory and the page that has the error may be in a different directory.

`directory1/directory2/thispagecausesa404error.php`

`directory1/thispagecausesa404error.php`

If I have `include includepage.php;` in my errordocument page, then it won't work.

I resolved to adding `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includepage.php';` to the errordocument page, which solves the problem, but I suspect that I am doing something wrong or not seeing the proper way to have a flawless include on an error page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. You can't use relative file specifiers inside error documents. Adding `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend never relying on `DOCUMENT_ROOT` being set correctly. Instead, use a relative path from the current script via the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php), eg

```
include __DIR__ . '/relative/path/from/this/script/to/includepage.php';
```

The path can also contain parent directory traversal via `../` if required, eg

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../some/dir/includepage.php';
```